# Get last number from editbox Matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers, brackets, trigonometry

I am making calculator with matlab and I want to take last input number from editbox and put it into sind() brackets, when sin button is pushed. How to do that? I searched for several hours and didn't found anything.

Now my code for sin button looks like that:

```
  % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton40.
function pushbutton40_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
inpfieldtxt = get(handles.edit1,'string');
if(strcmp(inpfieldtxt,'0.')==1)
    set(handles.edit1,'String','sind(');
else
    inpfieldtxt=strcat(inpfieldtxt,'sind(');
    set(handles.edit1,'String',inpfieldtxt)
end
```

It just inserts 'sind(' to editbox and then I manually need to input number and closing bracket ')'.

I want this button to react as Windows 7 calculator's sin button. It also gets last number and puts it into sin(here).

I GOT IT!
Here is solution:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton40.
function pushbutton40_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
inpfieldtxt = get(handles.edit1,'string');
if(strcmp(inpfieldtxt,'0.')==1)
    set(handles.edit1,'String','sind(');
else
    isNumber = (inpfieldtxt >= '0') & (inpfieldtxt <= '9');
    i=length(inpfieldtxt);
    while (i > 0) && (isNumber(i))
        if isNumber(i)
            i = i-1;
        end
    end
    lastnmb = inpfieldtxt(i+1:end);
    inpfieldtxt = inpfieldtxt(1:i);
    set(handles.edit1,'String',[inpfieldtxt,'sind(',lastnmb,')']);
end
```

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: It seems like you are trying to do everything in 1 step here, and when things aren't working you can't tell whats broken.  I suggest you rework your code.  Instead of having a few lines, determine the steps required to solve your problem and address 1 step per line. Then when things don't work you can test individual lines to see where things are breaking down.

Comment: I just don't get how (isNumber(i)) works. How it sees if my input is number from the end? I understand that it is 5 if I input 56+54, but then isNumber(5).

Comment: I realized :D isNumber is ivedlauktxt from 0 to 9 and we watch if it is number and then length is decreased by one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ivedlauktxt(end)` gives the last character

On second thought, you may want to look into `str2num()`

Edit:

Given the specific thing you are looking for this could be a way to do it:

```
isNumber = (ivedlauktxt >= '0')  & (ivedlauktxt <= '9')
i=length(ivedlauktxt); %Initialize loop
while i>0   && (isNumber(i))
   if isNumber(i)
      i=i-1;
   end
end

str2num( ivedlauktxt(i+1:end) )
```

Did not test it but it should get you there!

Comment: I need not last character, but last number until signs *,/,+,-.
For example I input 65+51, and when push sin, 51 must be put into sin brackets and result will be 65+sind(51)

Comment: Updated the post to find the end untill the first non-number. Should be easy to change if you only want to exclude these few signs.

Comment: Not working. Get these errors:
Operands to the || and && operators must be
convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in ManoSkaiciuokle2>pushbutton40_Callback
(line 355)
    isNumber = (ivedlauktxt >= '0') &&
    (ivedlauktxt <= '9');

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ManoSkaiciuokle2 (line 17)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)ManoSkaiciuokle2('pushbutton40_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: Fixed, should not have used `&&`, just `&`

Comment: Nothing changes, sind( is just added to the end. How I need to change my line ivedlauktxt=strcat(ivedlauktxt,'sind('); to work with your code?